# Instantiating in Array

Tags: actionscript-3

I have these three objects that i need to add on stage, when I extract them from the array on a later stage of the program.

I can't write `var mall: Mall = new Mall ();` because somebody told me before that, This will add in the object in the memory and will be really bad if a lot of objects are being handled. I will have a lot more objects to work with later on.

So I would like to know a way that when i run a for loop or an event listener i can add  `... = new object ();` automatically and then call addchild to make an instance of the object.

```
var mall:Mall;
var library:Library;
var music:Music;

var choices:Array = new Array ();

choices.push(mall,library,music);
```

---

test Code for Garbage Collection :

```
var waking: WakingUp = new WakingUp ();
addChild (waking);
waking.y=-30;
waking.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, waking_up);
function waking_up (g:Event){
if (waking.currentFrame == waking.totalFrames)
{
    waking.stop ();
    waking.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME,waking_up);

        removeChild (waking);
        removeChild(alarm_slide);


        gotoAndStop (6);


}

}
```

This is all the ref I have to this code :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addChild does not make an instance of the object, it simply adds the object to the displaylist of the current display container.

Using `new Mall()` is fine - just ensure that you remove references to it when it's no longer required so that it may be garbage collected. Alternatively you can just hold an array of primitives.

Comment: oh I see :D can u tell me how can i remove the refernce ? but that is also bad becuase I will have certain objects that will remain and certain that won't. so i won't be able to tell which ones to remove and which ones to not.

Comment: Remove the event listeners to the object and remove it from the array. Why won't you be able to tell which ones to remove?

Comment: oh I see, so if I remove the listeners the Garbage collector would be able to catch it? I wouldn't have to null it or something?

Comment: You will need to remove it from the array, using either pop, shift or splice. Ref: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html

Comment: Oh thank you very much for teaching me something new. I will do that :D

Answer (score 3):

Specific to instantiating your array with elements, you can:

```
var choices:Array = [ mall, library, music ];
```

Flash Player runtime uses both reference counting as well as mark and sweep.

So, any reference to the instance adds a count - collections, display list, event listeners, class members... as instances are dereferenced, the memory will ultimately be freed.

**Reference Counting**

> Each object on the heap keeps track of the number of things pointing to it. Each time you create a reference to an object, the
>   object's reference count is incremented. When you delete a reference,
>   the object's reference count is decremented. If the object has a zero
>   reference count (nothing is pointing to it), it is added to the Zero
>   Count Table (ZCT). When the ZCT is full, the stack is scanned to find
>   any references from the stack to an object on the ZCT. Any object on
>   the ZCT without a stack reference is deleted.
>
> One of the problems of deferred reference counting is circular references. If ObjectA and ObjectB refer to each other but no other
>   objects in the system point to them, they will never have a zero
>   reference count and will therefore never be eligible for garbage
>   collection using reference counting. This is where mark and sweep
>   garbage collection helps.

**Mark/Sweep**

> Applications that run in Flash Player or AIR have multiple GCRoots.
>   You can think about a GCRoot as the trunk of a tree with the objects
>   of the application as the branches. The Stage is a GCRoot. Loaders are
>   GCRoots. Certain menus are GCRoots. Every object that is still in use
>   by the application is reachable from one of the GCRoots within the
>   application. GCRoots are never garbage collected.
>
> Every object in an application has a "mark bit." When the Mark phase
>   of garbage collection begins, all of those mark bits are cleared. The
>   MMgc keeps track of all GCRoots in the application. The garbage
>   collector starts from those roots, traces through each object and sets
>   the mark bit for every object it reaches. Any object that is no longer
>   reachable from any of the roots is no longer reachable from anywhere
>   in the application – its mark bit does not get set during the Mark
>   phase. Once the collector is done marking all of the objects it finds,
>   the Sweep phase begins. Any object that doesn't have a set mark bit is
>   destroyed and its memory reclaimed.

Comment: AHHHHH THis is so useful. Thank you so much for sharing this. My app had a lot of memory leaks Now I know why. so just to check the understanding, I uploaded a little piece of code in my question can u please tell me if that will be garbage collected?

Comment: In your example, `waking` should be disposed as all references are removed - it's removed from the display list and its event listener is removed.  Flash Builder features a profiler that lets you see current and cumulative instances, and Flash Pro now features [Scout](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/scout/articles/adobe-scout-getting-started.html) which helps profile memory of your application.

Comment: Oh I see that is such a  useful tool. Thanks so much for teaching me this.